# Is there a way to minimize size of libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I got used to track my apps by GA. However I haven't payed attention before to its size, until I added ipad, iphone 6/6+ support to my app, and size increased over 50 mb. I deem it really awful for a utility app. But all those png's with high resolution graphics produce valuable size content and libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a, which now has size of 11,4 MB. I attach GA version 3 using cocoapods, is there a way to minimize the library?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?